# Javascript TypeError: var not defined, but alert shows content of var

Tags: javascript, string, variables, replace

i've got an problem with my replace method.

```
function replacePlaceHolder(description) {
    return description.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
}
```

The error is: TypeError: description is undefined

But description is defined, if I do `alert(description);`, i get the content of description.

If it try it without the replace method it works:

```
function replacePlaceHolder(description) {
    return description;
}
```

I think it's a little problem, but I don't get it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: the problem might come from your `description` call. `replacePlaceHolder("foo \n bar")` doesn't throw any error for me. try to add `console.log(description);` before `return` and make sure you're passing a string to your func

Comment: Thanks the problem is solved, String(description).replace worked for me!